# Nested JSON output for Primary and Foreign key Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Iam using Django 3.2 with Restframework.
I have a Model as a for a Primary key named Tag and a Model connected as a foreign key named TagItem.

I tried to get a nested JSON output for it but its not working as expected.

Models.py

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tagId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100,default=1)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class TagItem(models.Model):
    tagId= models.ForeignKey(Tags, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    select = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
def get_tag_details(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tag = Tags.objects.all()
        tagitem = TagItem.objects.all()

        TagSerializeobj = TagsSerializer(tag,many=True)
        TagItemSerializeobj = TagItemSerializer(tagitem, many=True)
        result = {}
        result['tag'] = TagSerializeobj.data
        for item in TagItemSerializeobj:
            if item.tagId == result['tag'].tagId:
                result['tagItem'] = item
        return Response(result)
```

Error: `'ListSerializer' object is not iterable`
How to iterate of get items nested under related Tags only.

Required output

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "section": "crafts",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "10",
          "select": false,
          "name": "Wood"
        },
        {
          "id": "11",
          "select": false,
          "name": "Clay"
        }
    ]
},
   {
      "id": 2,
      "section": "states",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "20",
          "select": false,
          "name": "Andhra Pradesh"
        },
        {
          "id": "21",
          "select": false,
          "name": "Arunachal Pradesh"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all those processing in your views. `ModelSerializer` can do it for you, so you can just define a model serializer for `TagItem` that is nested on a model serializer for `Tag` so something like:

```
class TagItemModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TagItem
        fields = '__all__'


class TagModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_items(self, obj):
        return TagItemModelSerializer(obj.tag_items.all(), many=True)
```

And in your views:

```
serializer = TagModelSerializer(Tags.objects.all(), many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You can add [`depth = 1`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) at `Meta` instead of using `serializers.SerializerMethodField()`

Comment: Hi @bdbd, Gives a good path for nested serializers. But while implementing it give ```get_items() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```. Should the function need no parameters?

Comment: Does this doc "https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships" be helpful? Or do you suggest some else?

Comment: Edited. Forgot to use `self` so it should be: `def get_items(self, obj):`

Comment: I wanted to show how it would work with two serializers but as @Klim Bim said, it's also an option to use `depth = 1`.

Comment: Also yes, thats the doc you can read to have more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

I get unexpected keyword error when i tried to assign

Comment: Hi @Nik, With the error you shared, it looks like, the keyword passed during POST request is either incorrect or missing. Like "section" is entered as "sections" etc etc.